# extends AbstractMap make me see UnsupportedOperationException for method put

Tags: java

I'm trying to realize a personal abstractMap. I have 2 types of map in my project, one `<String , List<Box>>` and one `<String , Box>` (box is a class for encase an item with his quantity). But when I try the put method of map, it's showing me "UnsupportedOperationException - if the put operation is not supported by this map"

This is the abstract class for map

```
public abstract class TamagotchiMap<X> extends AbstractMap<String, X> {

  @Override
  public abstract Set<Entry<String, X>> entrySet();


  public abstract void attachCategories(Set<String> categories);


  public abstract void addItemForCategory(String category, Box box);


  public abstract String getCategory(Box box);


  public Collection<String> getAllCategories() {
    return this.keySet();
  }



}
```

and there are the 2 classes that extends this class

1)

```
public class InventoryMainMap extends TamagotchiMap<Box> {

private final Set<Entry<String, Box>> entry = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public Set<Entry<String, Box>> entrySet() {
    return entry;
}


@Override
public void attachCategories(final Set<String> categories) {
    for (String category: categories) {
        this.put(category, null);
    }
}



/**
 * 
 * @return main item for this category
 * @param category is the category of item
 */
public Box getMainItem(final String category) {
    return this.get(category);
}

@Override
public String getCategory(final Box box) {
    for (String category: this.getAllCategories()) {
        if (this.get(category).containsItem(box.getItem())) {
            return category;
        }
      }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void addItemForCategory(final String category, final Box box) {
    if (this.containsKey(category)) {
        this.replace(category, box);
    }
}
}
```

2)

```
public class ItemContainerMap extends TamagotchiMap<List<Box>> {

private final Set<Entry<String, List<Box>>> entry = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public Set<Entry<String, List<Box>>> entrySet() {
    return entry;
}

@Override
public String getCategory(final Box box) {
    for (String category: this.getAllCategories()) {
        for (Box boxIterator: this.get(category)) {
            if (boxIterator.containsItem(box.getItem())) {
                return category;
            }
         }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void addItemForCategory(final String category, final Box box) {
    if (this.containsKey(category)) {
       if (!this.get(category).contains(box)) {
           System.out.println("nuovo item");
           this.get(category).add(box);
       } else {
           System.out.println("item esistente");
           this.get(category).stream().filter(iterBox -> iterBox.equals(box)).forEach(iterBox -> iterBox.increaseQuantity());
       }
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

}

@Override
public void attachCategories(final Set<String> categories) {
    for (String category: categories) {
        this.put(category, new LinkedList<Box>());
    }
}

}
```

When I do

```
class Test {

   TamagotchiMap map = new ItemContainerMap();
   map.put(string, box); 

}
```

it makes me see the Exception that I have already said. 
As if the put was not usable, do you know where I was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` is the default implementation of `put(K, V)` you inherit from `AbstractMap`. You could either implement it yourself, or, have your `TamagotchiMap` extend a concrete `Map` class, such as `HashMap` instead of `AbstractMap`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, now the problem is the put, how can i make put method ??